# Is it possible to download two separate files from two separate servers as one file?

Tags: download, server, vimeo

As extra information to the question, only one of the servers is mine. I have a Vimeo PRO account that allows permanent download links and would like to include some of my videos inside other downloads from my site. We have the videos on our server accordingly but it would cut back on server traffic if the video was coming from Vimeo as well as several other benefits. This leads back to the overlying question, is it possible to download two files from two different servers but have them download on the users computer as one folder?

Comment: folder? file? download? download how? what? what language?

Comment: @PeeHaa When the user clicks on the download link my company provides, I want it to also download the video "file" from Vimeo and add it appropriately within a set of folders that would be compressed within a zip. I am not too concerned with compression at this point, just want to know if it is possible. I use PHP but I am looking for an answer in most any language